# Finding all which match

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I'm having a bit of trouble with MongoDb.

Suppose I have a collection of MyObject where:

```
MyObject
{
    public Guid Guid { get;set; }
    public List<BsonValue> Identifiers { get;set; }
    public List<string> Tags { get;set; }
}
```

Now I insert a bunch of objects with the Identifiers set like:

```
new List<BsonValue>{"A"} *
new List<BsonValue>{"D"}
new List<BsonValue>{"A", "B"} *
new List<BsonValue>{"C", "D"}
new List<BsonValue>{"A", "B", "C"} *
new List<BsonValue>{"A", "B", "C", "D"}
```

Now I come along with a test case which contains the following values:

```
"A", "B", "C"
```

I want to retrieve the records marked with an * above... I have toyed with the Query.In but I am getting an error *Cannot deserialize Guid from BsonType ObjectId*

A LITTLE EXTRA CLARITY:

I have managed to achieve what I want through code. However I would be delighted if someone can point me in the direction of a simpler method. This will do however.

```
var query = new List<BsonValue>{"A","B","C"};

var results = collection.FindAs<MyObject>(Query.In("Identifiers", query));
var valid = results.Where(r => !r.Identifiers.Except(a).Any()).ToList();
```

Comment: Fixed the issue at the end there. I wasn't clearing out my database. Cleared it and started fresh - happy now. Query.In returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = new List<BsonValue>{"A","B","C"};

var results = collection.FindAs<MyObject>(Query.In("Identifiers", query));
var valid = results.Where(r => !r.Identifiers.Except(a).Any()).ToList();
```